# PHP PDO Doesn't insert new records

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, prepared-statement

I do not understand what my problem seem to be.
I got the following PHP code:

```
include_once 'db.inc.php';
    try 
    {
        $db = new PDO(DB_INFO, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo 'Connection failed: ', $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }

    $title = htmlentities($_POST['title']);
    $entry = htmlentities($_POST['entry']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO entries (title, entry) VALUES (?, ?)"; 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute(array($title, $entry)); 
    $stmt->closeCursor();
```

I do not receive any error of any kind and the script seem to have worked however it does not insert anything into the database. 
No matter what I try it doesn't do anything.

---

### edit

Sorted :)
I didn't know about `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`.

It gave me "Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected'".

Turns out I wrote `mysql:host=127.0.0.1;db_name=test1` instead of `mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test1` in my config file.

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Enable proper error reporting during development. Change your `php.ini` or put this at the top of your script `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Why are you HTML encoding the values before inserting them? Also, insert statements do not generate a cursor and therefor, do not need closing

Comment: Have you tried checking to see if there's anything in `errorInfo()`?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) doesn't report anything, errorInfo() either.

Comment: @user996459 Is `display_errors` enabled? If not, you won't see any errors

Comment: @user996459 Show you updated code,

Comment: try to dump debug info

var_dump($stmt->debugDumpParams());
var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());

Comment: @Phil Yes, I used `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of my script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set PDO to throw exceptions when execution fails

```
$db = new PDO(DB_INFO, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Won't make a difference to this script

Comment: Thanks this helped. It gave me SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected error. Turns out I wrote `mysql:host=127.0.0.1;db_name=test1` instead of `mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test1` in my config file. Not so easy to spot for a noob like myself!